# Strict Typing for Mongoose Populate

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

Is there any way to define / amend an interface or type as to ***assert*** that a document will be populate in typescript using mongoose?

e.g.

```
interface ISchool {
   name: string;
   address; string;
}
interface IPerson {
   name: string;
   school?: PopulatedDoc<ISchool & Document>
}
const PersonSchema: Schema<IPerson> = new Schema<IPerson>({
    name: { type: String },
    school: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School' }
})
const Person = mongoose.model<IPerson>('Person', PersonSchema);
export default Person
```

Then essentially if we ever interact with a Person document, there is no way of knowing if the `school` property is populated of not.
eg.

```
const person = await Person.findOne({});
if (person.school) { . . . } // is `school` an ObjectId or a Document?
```

and

```
const person = await Person.findOne({}, undefined, { populate: { path: 'school', model: 'School'} });
if (person.school) { . . . } // is `school` an ObjectId or a Document?
```

Is there any way to assert that a document property has been populated?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [populate-with-typescript](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/populate.html) documentation, we can:

> add a generic parameter `Paths` to the `populate()`

```
import mongoose, { Types } from 'mongoose';

interface ISchool {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}
interface IPerson {
    name: string;
    school?: Types.ObjectId;
}
const PersonSchema: mongoose.Schema<IPerson> = new mongoose.Schema<IPerson>({
    name: { type: String },
    school: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'School' },
});

const Person = mongoose.model<IPerson>('Person', PersonSchema);

(async function run() {
    const person1 = await Person.findOne({});
    person1?.school; // school is ObjectId

    const person2 = await Person.findOne({}).populate<{ school: ISchool }>({ path: 'school', model: 'School' });
    person2?.school; // scholl is ISchool
})();
```